# Syntax error in writing a SQL sas code using case when and like statements

Tags: sql, function, syntax-error, sas, sql-like

See code below. For a specific industry e.g. "Fss" there are a list of titles against which the variable job title has to be matched for flag creation.

```
   proc sql;
   create table ildp.ildp_1h_v5 as
   select industry,jobtitle,webpagesource,assetname,qtr,companyname,
   case 
   when industry = "FSS" and (jobtitle like 'CMO%' OR jobtitle like 'Chief Innovation)
   then 1
   else case when ..#continued.#
```

Comment: `select *, case`? perhaps if you sprinkled some `FROM` magic powder on there, the statement would be able to fly... Of course, the REST of the query is just flat-out wrong as well... so my suggestion would to be learn BASIC sql syntax before tackling this.

Comment: It's supposed to run on which database?

Comment: Sas bdat file running in sas

Comment: Sorry I was new to stack and not familiar with the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`or like` is not valid SQL.  Try this:

```
proc sql;
create table ildp.ildp_1h_v3 as
select *,
       (case when industry = "FSS" and
                  (jobtitle like 'CIO%'
                   OR jobtitle like 'ChiefInnovation%' 
                   OR jobtitle like 'director%'
                   OR jobtitle like 'head%'
                   OR jobtitle like 'distribution%'
                   OR jobtitle like 'claims%'
                   OR jobtitle like 'VP%'
                   OR jobtitle like 'President%')
             then 1 else 0
        end) as title_flag
from ildp.ildp_1h_v2;

quit;
```